# Why doesn't this code work on android 6 marshmallow Api 23?

Tags: android, telephonymanager, android-6.0-marshmallow

Why doesn't this code work on android 6 marshmallow Api 23? It does not throw an Exception but the code within callStateListener does not work.

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
PhoneStateListener callStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        //if(logAtive) Log.i(LOG_TAG,incomingNumber + " " + state);
        if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hey, receive your call. Phone is ringing.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You are in a call. ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You are in idle state… ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};

telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Permissions:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_INCOMING_CALLS" />
```

It works perfectly in Android 5.1.1 but not in 6 (API Level 23)

Comment: maybe because of new permission model

Comment: That code does not do anything. You create a `PhoneStateListener` and then do not do anything with it.

Comment: Android does not have android.permission.PROCESS_INCOMING_CALLS permission now, it used to be there earlier, check permissions

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into this and figured it out.  It's because you are targeting android SDK 23. If you change your manifest file to target API 22 then it will start working even when installed and running on a Marshmallow device.

If you still want to target API 23 then you have to use the new runtime permission API to request permission usage first, otherwise it will simply be denied.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: do we need to change the target API in build.gradle(Module:app) file also??please let me know i too face the same problem..

Answer (score 3):

You may not have any permissions to access the `TelephonyManager` (for example `READ_PHONE_STATE`).

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html), when you have not requested or have not been granted permission, but are still trying to access it, the result will be empty, rather than an exception like in the past:

> If a user turns off permissions for a legacy app, the system silently disables the appropriate functionality. When the app attempts to perform an operation that requires that permission, the operation will not necessarily cause an exception. Instead, it might return an empty data set, signal an error, or otherwise exhibit unexpected behavior. For example, if you query a calendar without permission, the method returns an empty data set.

You need to ask the user to grant the appropriate permission, and handle cases when the user has already denied or has revoked that permission etc. There's a detailed description of how to employ this [here](http://blog.safedk.com/technology/the-marshmallows-are-coming-new-permissions-model-is-almost-here?ref=so).

Answer (score 1):

I observed the very same behavior. Our app works perfectly well on Lollipop and down, but not on Marshmallow. It has nothing to do with permissions. Actually with the test app I wrote, I just went into Settings and gave the permissions beforehand. The problem in our app was with a phone number itself, that came from external source. If Android thinks it's not valid, you won't get `onCallStateChanged` called on Marshmallow. Just use a fake number `1234567890,,2#` ("invalid") vs `1234567890` ("valid") to validate it. I don't know how to "fix" the number yet, as part of the numbers with extensions work.
Edit: [bug report I've opened at 16 Dec. 15](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=197208)

Answer (score 0):

Please, post your AndroidManifest, as well as [check the following documeetation:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html)

> Note that access to some telephony information is permission-protected. Your application won't receive updates for protected information unless it has the appropriate permissions declared in its manifest file. Where permissions apply, they are noted in the appropriate LISTEN_ flags.
>
> > [(Source:)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#onCallStateChanged%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) incoming call phone number. If application does not have READ_PHONE_STATE permission, an empty string will be passed as an argument.